# Error al actualizar datos - TypeError: put() got multiple values for argument 'connection'

Tags: firebase, python-3.9

Estoy trabajando con *Firebase* y Python, pero tengo un peque error cuando intento agregar estos datos a un usuario en especifico y me esta generando el siguiente error ,gracias espero que me ayuden

```
TypeError: put() got multiple values for argument 'connection'
```

**Mi código**

```py
def Newcompra(user,items):
    global PlayerDB,TiendaDB
    
    info = {
        "id": TiendaDB[items]["id"],
        "nombre": TiendaDB[items]["nombre"],
        "historia": TiendaDB[items]["historia"],
        "tipo": TiendaDB[items]["tipo"],
        "g_type": TiendaDB[items]["g_type"],
        "peso": TiendaDB[items]["peso"],
        "tier": TiendaDB[items]["tier"],
        "envolver": TiendaDB[items]["envolver"],
        "evento_item": TiendaDB[items]["evento_item"],
        "fabricable": TiendaDB[items]["fabricable"],
        "intercanbio": TiendaDB[items]["intercanbio"],
        "precio": TiendaDB[items]["precio"],
        "venta": TiendaDB[items]["venta"],
        "atributos": {
            "ataque": TiendaDB[items]["atributos"]["ataque"],
            "defensa": TiendaDB[items]["atributos"]["defensa"],
            "mana": TiendaDB[items]["atributos"]["mana"],
            "habilidad": TiendaDB[items]["atributos"]["habilidad"],
            "nivel": TiendaDB[items]["atributos"]["nivel"]
           
    }
}

    Fire.put("/players",user,"/bolso_arm",items,info)

    return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo He añadido una "/" antes de "user".

Fire.put ("/ players /" + user + "/ bolso_arm", items, info)

Ahora solo hay tres parámetros .